# Limit of diagram consisting of two maps $f: M \to N$ and $g: N \to M$ where $M,N$ are $R$-modules.

Tags: category-theory, modules

Suppose $f: M \to N$ and the map $g: N \to M$, where $M$ and $N$ are $R$-mdoules. We wish to find the limit over the diagram
$$M \rightleftarrows N$$
in the two cases: (1) Where $fg = 1_N$ and $gf = 1_M$; (2) When $fg$ and $gf$ are *not* necessarily the identity on their respective modules.

Assuming that $f \circ g = 1_N$ and $g \circ f = 1_M$, then I've tried a few candidates for the limit object, call it $L$. The problem is that I can never seem to get the limit cone to commute.

If $L = M/\operatorname{im} g \oplus N/\operatorname{im} f$, and the legs of the cone are the canonical projection maps $\pi_1, \pi_2$, then for this to actually commute we must have
$$f \circ \pi_1 (m + \operatorname{im} g \oplus n + \operatorname{im} f) = f(m) = \pi_2 (n)$$
where the right-hand side is only in the image of $f$ if in fact $n$ is zero and hence $m$ is in the kernel of $f$. This gives me the feeling that the limit is in fact the zero-module, the terminal object. But this does not seem to satisfy the commutativity condition for the legs of the cones.

I also tried $M/\ker f \oplus N/ \ker g$ and even $\operatorname{ker} f/ \operatorname{im} g \oplus \ker g/ \operatorname{im} f$.

I am not having any luck, and have spent many hours thinking about this problem and I suspect the answer is somewhat trivial.

Comment: A nice exercise in manipulating cones (which also happens to be relevant here) is proving that the limit of a diagram which includes an initial object is isomorphic to that initial object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is the subset of pairs $(m,n)$ of $M\times N$ satisfying $f(m)=n$ and $g(n)=m$.

When $fg=1_N$, one of the conditions becomes redundant, and we just require $g(n)=m$ for all pairs $(m,n)$, so the limit is $\{(g(n),n)|n\in N\}\cong N$.

Likewise if $gf=1_M$, the limit is just $M$.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that $$\{(m,n)\in M\times N\mid f(m) = n\text{ and }g(n) = m\}\cong \{m\in M\mid g(f(m)) = m\}\cong \{n\in N\mid f(g(n)) = n\},$$ so in the general case we can realize the limit as a submodule of $M$ or of $N$.

Comment: Yes, that's nice.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to express this module in terms of direct products and kernels?

Comment: @JohnCavanaugh Sure, the limit is the kernel of the map $M\times N\to M\times N$ given by $f(m,n) = (m-g(n),n-f(m))$.